# JParallax Scrollbar - Can it be done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

Have a rather simple question.

Does anyone knows if i can use jparallax both with mouse and scrollbars?
Is there any way to bind the mouse movement with scrollbars?

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know some javascript plugins allow mapping the scrollwheel like: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel so yes you can (but it's possible you'll have to write something yourself to link to jParallax)